# Every Hilbert space operator is a combination of projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory

I am reading a paper on Hilbert space operators, in which the authors used a surprising result

> Every $X\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is a finite linear combination of orthogonal projections.

The author referred to a 1967 paper by Fillmore, Sums of operators of square zero. However, this paper is not online.

I wonder whether someone has a hint on how this could be true since there are all kinds of operators while projections have such a regular and restricted form.

Thanks!

Comment: The mathscinet article says summary that "(...)every operator on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is (1) a sum of 64
operators with square zero and (2) a linear combination of 257 projections.". I think it's probably important that it is a separable space. Makes you wonder how did they exactly count the 257 projections. ;)

Comment: @tomasz: You can generalize from the separable case to the infinite dimensional case by writing $\mathcal{H}$ as an orthogonal sum of separable $X$-invariant subspaces. For self-adjoint operators, this won't increase the number of projections needed. As every operator is a sum of self-adjoint ones, this allows the separability condition to be removed.

Comment: The number 257 was improved to 10 by Matsumoto 30 years ago. See this paper by Laurent Marcoux: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/Preprints/Mar2009Projections.pdf

Comment: I cannot access this paper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answers you're looking for can be found in a paper by Pearcy and Topping, [Sums of small numbers of idempotents.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-14/issue-4/Sums-of-small-numbers-of-idempotents/10.1307/mmj/1028999848.full), which is openly accessible.