# non-existence of nonzero special linear map on $B(H)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I saw an exercise :There is no nonzero linear map $\phi:B(H) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\phi(ab)=\phi(ba)$ when $dim(H)=\infty$.
I have no idea.Can anyone give me some hints,thanks!

Comment: You might want to check out this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860886/no-trace-on-bh-if-h-is-infinite-dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $B(H)$ is infinite, for $H$ infinite dimensional.

Take two isometries $S_0,S_1 \in  B(H)$ such that $S_0S_0^* + S_1S_1^* = 1$. Now see what happens if you apply your map $\phi$ to that equation.

Comment: I'm curious what your argument is. One gets easily that $\phi$ is zero on infinite projections, but [my own argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860911/22857) to conclude that $\phi$ is zero is a bit clumsy.

Comment: @Martin Argerami,I think your argument is very clear.