# Density of orthogonal projections in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a (for simplicity seperable) Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ denote the space of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$. Since characteristic functions are total in $L^\infty$, we know by the Borel functional calculus that the orthogonal projections are total in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

However, let $\mathbb{1}$ denote the identity on $\mathcal{H}$ and let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$, then $\mathbb{1}=\sum_n \langle \cdot,e_n \rangle e_n$ holds in SOT but not in norm (as it is not a Cauchy sequence).

In my opinion it is really surprising that we have totality of orthogonal projetions in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ but even for the simplest operator the most natural approximation doesn't work.

Therefore my question is: Why is this theorem heuristically true (beyond the class of compact operators)?

Best, Sebastian

**edit**: replaced dense by total (I often use those terms synonymously in TVS despite it is formally not correct)

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.

Comment: I know that it is true that the orthogonal projections are total in the space of bounded operators. Now I want to understand "why" it is true (from an intuitive point of view). My given "counterexample" made me belief (before I have proved it) that it is very implausible that this theorem holds.

Comment: I still don't know what you are asking. If you mean the set of *all* orthogonal projections in $B(H)$, then every operator is a linear combination of projections, no limits involved. If you mean just the family $\langle\cdot,e_n\rangle e_n$ for a fixed orthonormal basis, such set is not total even in finite dimension.

Comment: Can you give a reference for your first assertion? I have never heard this and I can't imagine that this should be true...

Comment: Every operator on $B(H)$ is a linear combination of 10 projections. Most references I know are mentioned in [this paper](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/Preprints/Mar2009Projections.pdf) of Laurent Marcoux. Others (or the same) references appear in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162214/every-hilbert-space-operator-is-a-combination-of-projections).

Comment: Very astonishing! Thanks!